Enumerating all finite models up to isomorphism
For bit of context, please read the answers to this previous question of mine.
Given a FO language $L$ with finitely many constant and relation symbols. I don't understand why the set of finite $L$-structures that are isomorphic to each other (I am not sure what it means exactly) is countable, and hence can be effectively enumerated.
Suppose $L$ has $3$ constant symbols, say $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$. What are all possible finite $L$-structures that are isomorphic to each other? Are there finitely many such structures? I think that the domain of all finite $L$-structures will contain up to $3$ elements and is a finite subset of $\mathbb N$ (for some reason, it cannot be a finite subset of $\mathbb R$?). That is, the possible domains are $\{0\}$, $\{5\}$, $\{82\}$, $\{4, 51\}$, $\{54, 3, 17\}$, etc.. Besides domain, we must assign interpretation to symbols $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$. They will obviously get assigned values from the domain.

There are countably many finite $L$-structures up to isomorphism means the following. We can find a countable set $S$ consisting of finite $L$-structures so that every possible finite $L$-structure is isomorphic to one of the structures in the set $S$. It does not mean that "there are finitely many $L$-structures that are isomorphic to each other"! Indeed, any structure in any language has infinitely many isomorphic copies.

You can prove it like this: (1) if $M$ is an $L$-structure of cardinality $n$, then $M$ is isomorphic to some $L$-structure whose underlying set is ${1, \dotsc, n}$. (2) There is an algorithm that, given $k$ and $n$, enumerates all $k$-ary functions and all $k$-ary relations on ${1, \dotsc, n}$. Do you see why that suffices? Can you fill in the gaps?

@IzaakvanDongen Sorry, I don't see the point of (2).

The statements I made in my comments to the linked question got quite garbled when they made the transition to your current question. So let me give the high level summary, and then I'll give details, and then I'll address some of the garbling.
Throughout this answer, fix a finite language $L$. Write $\mathcal{S}$ for the proper class of all finite $L$-structures.
For $n\in \mathbb{N}$, let $[n]$ be the set $\{0,\dots,n-1\}$. Call an $L$-structure special if its domain is $[n]$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Write $\mathcal{S}'$ for the set of all special $L$-structures.
I want to make three main claims:

For every $A\in \mathcal{S}$, there exists $A'\in \mathcal{S}'$ such that $A\cong A'$.
For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, there are only finitely many $L$-structures with domain $[n]$, and they can be effectively enumerated, uniformly in $n$.
Therefore, the structures in $\mathcal{S}'$ can be effectively enumerated (and $\mathcal{S}'$ is countable).

As a consequence, we say that there are only countably many finite $L$-structures up to isomorphism, because by 1, every finite $L$-structure is isomorphic to a special structure, and by 3, there are only countably many special structures.
Applying this to your previous question: Given an $L$-sentence $\varphi$, we can search for a finite model of $\varphi$ by enumerating the structures in $\mathcal{S}'$ and checking whether each is a model of $\varphi$. If $\varphi$ has any finite model, say $A\models \varphi$, then since there is some $A'\in \mathcal{S}'$ such that $A\cong A'$, also $A'\models \varphi$, so our search will eventually find a finite model of $\varphi$, namely $A'$.

Claim 1: Let $A$ be a finite structure, and let $n = |A|$. Enumerate the $n$ elements of $A$ as $\{a_0,\dots,a_{n-1}\}$. I will define a structure $A'$ with domain $[n] = \{0,\dots,n-1\}$ (so $A'\in \mathcal{S}'$) such that the map $i\mapsto a_i$ is an isomorphism $A'\cong A$.

For each constant symbol $c$, there is a unique $i\in [n]$ such that $c^A = a_i$. Define $c^{A'} = i$.
For each function symbol $f$ of arity $k$, and all $i_1,\dots,i_k\in [n]$, there is a unique $j\in [n]$ such that $f^A(a_{i_1},\dots,a_{i_k}) = a_j$. Define $f^{A'}(i_1,\dots,i_k) = j$.
For each relation symbol $R$ of arity $k$, define $R^{A'} = \{(i_1,\dots,i_k)\mid (a_{i_1},\dots,a_{i_k})\in R^A\}$.

Now it is straightforward to check that $i\mapsto a_i$ is an isomorphism of $L$-structures.
Claim 2: To specify an $L$-structure $A$ with domain $[n]$, we must specify the following data.

For each constant symbol $c$, an element $c^A\in [n]$.
For each function symbol $f$ of arity $k$, a function $f^A\colon [n]^k\to [n]$.
For each relation symbol $R$ of arity $k$, a subset $R^A\subseteq [n]^k$.

For each symbol, there are only finitely many possible interpretations ($n$ for a constant symbol, $n^{n^k}$ for a function symbol, and $2^{n^k}$ for a relation symbol). And since $L$ is finite, we only need to make finitely many choices. So there are finitely many $L$-structures with domain $[n]$. I hope it is clear that we can effectively enumerate these finitely many structures in a uniform way (just iterate over all possible interpretations of each of the symbols in $L$).
Claim 3: Since $\mathcal{S}'$ is the union over all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ of the set of all $L$-structures with domain $[n]$, and a countable union of finite sets is countable, $\mathcal{S}'$ is countable. To effectively enumerate $\mathcal{S}'$, just enumerate the structures with domain $[0]$, then those with domain $[1]$, then those with domain $[2]$, etc.

Finally, let me respond to the misconceptions in your question.

I don't understand why the set of finite $L$-structures that are isomorphic to each other (I am not sure what it means exactly) is countable, and hence can be effectively enumerated.

The phrase "the set of finite $L$-structures that are isomorphic to each other" is nonsense, so you're right to not be sure what it means.

Suppose $L$ has $3$ constant symbols, say $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$. What are all possible finite $L$-structures that are isomorphic to each other? Are there finitely many such structures?

Ignoring the nonsense "that are isomorphic to each other", there is a proper class of finite $L$-structures, even of $L$-structures of size $1$. Indeed, for any set $x$, we can define an $L$-structure with domain the singleton $A = \{x\}$, interpreting each constant symbol $c_i$ in $A$ as the element $x$. Since there is no set of all sets, there is no set of all $L$-structures of size $1$.

I think that the domain of all finite $L$-structures will contain up to $3$ elements

No, an $L$-structure can contain any number of elements. There is no requirement that every element has to be named by a constant symbol.

and is a finite subset of $\mathbb N$ (for some reason, it cannot be a finite subset of $\mathbb R$?).

Of course a finite $L$-structure can have domain a finite subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (or of any other set). For example, we might have a structure $A = \{1, \pi, -\frac{3}{2}, 42\}$ with $c_1^A = 1$, $c_2^A = \pi$, and $c_3^A = 42$.
The point is that this structure $A$ is isomorphic to a structure $A'$ with domain $\{0,1,2,3\}$ with $c_1^{A'} = 0$, $c_2^{A'} = 1$, and $c_3^{A'} = 3$.
For the purpose of understanding all finite $L$-structures up to isomorphism, we don't actually care about whether the elements of the domain are natural numbers, or real numbers, or sets, or coffee cups. What matters is the structure of the symbols in the language on those elements. So we might as well focus our attention on structures whose domains are finite initial segments $[n]$ of the natural numbers.
